# How to select only bold text

Tags: text-editing

How can you select all of the bold text in a document? I would like to just extract bold text from numerous documents. Is there a script that could be run?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a document? A Word document, HTML, PDF?

Comment: Also what operating system are you running?

Comment: And what version of word ?

Comment: You do know that you can select all text that is under a certain style, so if one has properly edited the document something like that would be possible. Unfortunatelly, if no such option exists, I think it i snot possible. Word doesn't offer selection by text properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Word documents, you can use a VBA macro:

```
Open "C:\boldtext.txt" For Append As #1
Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
Write #1, Selection.Find.Text
Close #1
```

If it works as planned, it should add all bolded text in a document to a text file `C:\boldtext.txt`, where of course, it will no longer be bolded. I've never used VBA, just looked through a tutorial briefly and came up with this, maybe someone can test this for me?